# How to write this Linq query for this scenario?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a query I need to perform:

```
return entity.Messages.Include(m => m.User)
                      .Include(m => m.MessageRecipients.Select(u => u.User))
                      .First(m => m.MessageID == messageID);
```

This works fine on my local machine but it breaks on the webserver, despite the same setup. The problem is that I try to include the User

> Include(m => m.User)

but the user could not exist in the database anymore so it throws "Sequence contains no elements" because I use First().

Question: Is there a way to build the query in a way, so it does not brake when a user is not in DB? Something like outer join in SQL?

EDIT: If there's no User I still need the Message to be returned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the only way was to split the query in two:

`var message = entity.Messages
                     .Include(m => m.MessageRecipients.Select(u => u.User))
                     .First(m => m.MessageID == messageID);

var author = entity.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == message.AuthorUserID).FirstOrDefault();

if (author != null)
    message.User = author;

return message

`

Answer (score 1):

First() will throw exception like that, if you want null or default value returned when there is no element, then try to use FirstOrDefault().

Comment: will FirstOrDefault() still return the Message with the User property null? Or will the query return null?

Comment: The query will return null.

Comment: any idea on how to write this query to still return the instance of the Message?